Is this David Patterson 'Computer Architecture A Quantitative Approach' scheme right?

My guess is that L1 cache tag is also 28 bits as the L1 tag compare adress.
Another question is why the offset is going to CPU?
And the last one What other improvements and errors does this memory hierarchy scheme have that I am not seeing?

What is your question?  Make sure to state your question in the body of the post.  The title should be a short summary, but the body of your post should stand on its own.  The title is not intended to be just the first sentence of your post.  Please ask only one question per post.  I see three separate questions here.  If you have multiple questions, you can ask them separately.  What does "right" mean?

Please mention edition and (sub?)chapter title.

Your guess is right. In the sixth edition, there is a corrected version of it with the little change of the page offset size:
